# How to bind data service to another service class in Ninject?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, lambda, ninject.web.mvc

I am creating a view that displays all the information of a product on for my website. I want to create a "Details" service class, that handles most of my querying.
I binded my session to to my data in a GeneralWebApplicationDataNinjectModule:

```
Bind<IContentService>().To<ContentService>().InRequestScope();
        Bind<ISession>()
            .ToMethod(
                context =>
                    context.Kernel.Get<IMasterSessionSource>()
                        .ExposeConfiguration()
                        .BuildSessionFactory()
                        .OpenSession()
            )
            .WhenInjectedInto<IContentService>()
            .InRequestScope();
```

I have a ContentService class that pull all my data in that looks like this:

```
public interface IContentService
{
    IQueryable<Program> Programs { get; }
}

public class ContentService : IContentService
{
    private readonly ISession _session;
    public ContentService(ISession session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }

    public IQueryable<Program> Programs
    {
        get { return _session.Query<Program>(); }
    }

}
```

...this works fine when i load it into my Controller:

```
public class ProgramController : Controller
{
    private static IContentService _contentService;

    public ProgramController (IContentService contentService)
    {
        _contentService = contentService;
    }


public ActionResult Details(string item)
    {
        var ProgramDetails = DetailsService.ProgramsFind();
//this is where i want to use the service class to pull data in DetailsService.

        var model = new DetailPageViewModel
        {
            ProgramTables = GetUpComingCourses(),
        };

        return View("../Shared/DetailView", model);
    }
```

so i created a new service class to pull details trying to using ContentService:

```
public class DetailsService
{
    private static IContentService _contentService;

    public DetailsService(IContentService contentService)
    {
        _contentService = contentService;
    }


    public static IEnumerable<Programs> ProgramsFind()
    {
        var results =
            _contentService
                .Programs
                .Where(
                    d => d.TypeId >= 16 || d.TypeId <= 18);

        return results;
    }
```

i get a *System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code, Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object* on the line in ProgramsFind() where im calling _contentService. When i debug that it says its *null*.

So i realized this is because the data isnt binded to Details Service. When i enter in my InjectionDependency this:

```
    Bind<IContentService>().To<DetailsService>().InRequestScope();
```

i get a lot of errors where it wants me to implement everything thats in ContentService in DetailsService but i dont want to replicate that. i just want to use the content that ContentService found in my DetailsService. Much like how the controller easily does it.

I feel like theres something im missing...

**UPDATE**

i think i might have figured something out. I added IDetailsService to the Controller, and it seems to be successfully pulling queries.

```
 private static IContentService _contentService;
 // new
private static IDetailsService _detailsService;

    public MobileController(IContentService contentService, IDetailsService detailsService)
    {
        _contentService = contentService;
        //new
        _detailsService = detailsService;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that was the answer!

1. Create Service
2. Bind Sessions to Service
3. Add Service to the Controller.
4. Call Service when necessary.

As always, just something overlooked!